# Which side-effects may i face if i upgrade PSA 2.4 to 3.10 in dynamics 365?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-365

We are using Dynamics 365 online version (9.1). Our PSA version is 2.4 but as of Microsoft's requirements to upgrade all their clients to PSA version up to 3 we are wanting to upgrade PSA to (3.10).

My concerns is in following areas -

1. We have some customized **fields** in some entity like (order, quote, account etc). Will these persist if i upgrade PSA?
2. We have customized **JavaScript** which is attached in many events in different entity form. Will these persist or will go away if i upgrade PSA?

Any kind of help or suggestion would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to a sandbox instance in your tenant?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/power-platform/admin/sandbox-environments

I'd recommend investing in one or a few if possible. You can then do a **full backup and restore** of your main instance with PSA 2.4 into the sandbox, then do the upgrade in the sandbox instance and test.

Likely, the JS and field customization should persist, but the only real definitive way to confirm would be with a sandbox instance and an actual upgrade.